# How to Filter a Nested Object with array of String

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, search, filtering

```
let products = [
    {
        name: "A",
        color: "Blue",
        size: {
            size1: 1,
            size2: 2,
            size3: 3,
        },
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        color: "Blue",
        size: {
            size1: 5,
            size2: 19,
            size3: 22,
        },
    },
    { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
    { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 },
];
```

```
filters = ['Blue','2'];
```

the result must be the object that checks all strings in the array  for example

```
 {
    name: "A",
    color: "Blue",
    size: {
        size1: 1,
        size2: 2,
        size3: 3,
    },
},
```

the research must be accepted whatever the value in the

Comment: What does it mean by `'2'` here `filters = ['Blue','2']` ?

Comment: Why aren't you using an array for the size property: `size: [1,2,3]`?

Comment: @Asraf   it's the same principle as in Excel, I have an input and whatever values are written by the User, must be displayed all the objects that match these values, in combination

Comment: @adiga the array presents the inputs added by the User, the length can be varied

Comment: @kb9 that means it only matches string(s) of an object?

Comment: @Ashraf yes exactly

Comment: @kb9 and depth of your objects are known right?

Comment: @Asraf yes in fact my real object is nested and can have hundreds of objects

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve the nest via using a stack in some manner, either by recursion or iteratively using a stack explicitly. Here's a recursive solution:

```js
function getFiltered(obj, filters, found = null) {
    let outermostCall = (found === null);
    if (outermostCall) { //outermost call
        found = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < filters.length; index++) {
            found[index] = false;
        }
    }
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            let tempFound = getFiltered(obj[key], filters, found);
            for (let index = 0; index < found.length; index++) {
                if (tempFound[index]) found[index] = true;
            }
        } else {
            let foundIndex = -1;
            for (let index = 0; index < filters.length; index++) {
                if (filters[index] == obj[key]) {
                    foundIndex = index;
                    index = filters.length;
                }
            }
            if (foundIndex >= 0) {
                found[foundIndex] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (outermostCall) {
        return !found.filter(item => !item).length;
    }
    return found;
}

function getAllFiltered(array, filters) {
    let output = [];
    for (let obj of array) {
        if (getFiltered(obj, filters)) output.push(obj);
    }
    return output;
}

let products = [
    {
        name: "A",
        color: "Blue",
        size: {
            size1: 1,
            size2: 2,
            size3: 3,
        },
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        color: "Blue",
        size: {
            size1: 5,
            size2: 19,
            size3: 22,
        },
    },
    { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
    { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 },
];

let filters = ['Blue','2']; 

console.log(getAllFiltered(products, filters));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over any of the search values and check if all of them are in the object or nested objest for filtering.

```js
const
    has = f => {
        const check = o => o && typeof o === 'object'
            ? Object.values(o).some(check)
            : f === o;

        return check;
    },
    products = [{ name: "A", color: "Blue", size: { size1: 1, size2: 2, size3: 3 } }, { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: { size1: 5, size2: 19, size3: 22 } }, { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 }, { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 }],
    search = ['Blue', 2],
    result = products.filter(o => search.every(f => has(f)(o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.every` to check if all the filters are present in the object, if that's what you mean.

```js
const products = [
  { name: "A", color: "Blue", size: { size1:1, size2:2, size3:3 } },
  { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: { size1:5, size2:19, size3:22 } },
  { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
  { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 },
];

const filters = ['Blue','2'];

const filtered = products.filter(product => {
  return Object.values(product).every(value => {
    return filters.includes(value);
  });
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `strings` returns all nested strings within an object, converting any numbers to strings. Then, we just filter any product where the list of strings includes all necessary matches.

```js
const products = [{"name":"A","color":"Blue","size":{"size1":1,"size2":2,"size3":3}},{"name":"B","color":"Blue","size":{"size1":5,"size2":19,"size3":22}},{"name":"C","color":"Black","size":70},{"name":"D","color":"Green","size":50}];
const filters = ['Blue','2'];
const subsetMatch=(a,s)=>s.every(i=>a.includes(i));
const strings=i=>typeof i==='object'?Object.values(i).flatMap(strings):i+'';
console.log(products.filter(i=>subsetMatch(strings(i),filters)));
```